# URL to file forces download, how to disable downloading and store this file into a javascript variable in the client side?

Tags: javascript, file, media-player

I have a url to a .mp3 file and its forcing me to download it when loading it on the client side. Is there a way to disable this forced download and store this mp3 file into a variable so I can load it into my javascript mp3 player?

Comment: use ajax (XMLHttpRequest or fetch) `fetch(url).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {...})`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
  <a id="link" href="http://example.com/path/some.mp3">link</a>

  <script> 
    $("#link").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $("#link").attr("href");
        var a = new Audio(url);
        a.play();

});
  </script>
```